# How to find the number of the day in a year from yyyy-mm-dd using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this data:

```
Date        Time      VCD    
20041001    184531      293.7
20041001    202316      305.4
20041002    175015      322.9
20041002    192822      316.6
20041003    183314      334.4
```

I am using this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
frame1=pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Date','Time','VCD'])
clw1 = frame1.drop_duplicates('Date', keep='last')
```

With clw1 remove the duplicate data with a new column 'DateTime' yyyy-mm-dd

```
Date        Time      VCD       DateTime
20041001    184531      293.7   2004-10-01
20041002    175015      322.9   2004-10-02
20041003    183314      334.4   2004-10-03
```

I am trying obtain day of year, number of month and day of month (adding the respective columns in the frame1, for example adding a new column in frame1 for day of year (1....365 of 20014)

```
frame1['doye'] = frame1['DateTime'].apply(lambda x: dt.DatetimeIndex.dayofyear('DateTime'))
```

But error : AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'DatetimeIndex'
with Pandas 0.20.2 version
Probably I have problems with the concept of Pandas and datetime, many solutions suggested use individual data (values) or for old pandas version, how can I do working with columns using dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1: Using apply() (Not as good as method 2)

Try using this:

```
frame1["doye"] = frame1.DateTime.apply(lambda s: s.timetuple().tm_yday)
```

This applies a function to the DateTime column, so the lambda will return each datetime in the col. Therefore `s` is a DateTime object. I used the `timetuple()` function to get a [***`time.struct_time`***](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) object which has the member `tm_yday` to give you the day of the year.

This was my (scrappy) test code:

import numpy as np

```
import datetime as dt

data1 = [ {"Date" : "20041001", "Time" : 184531}]

frame1=pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Date','Time'])
frame1["DateTime"]= pd.to_datetime(frame1.Date, format="%Y%m%d", errors='raise')
print frame1
frame1["doye"] = frame1.DateTime.apply(lambda s: s.timetuple().tm_yday)
print frame1
```

The output was:

```
       Date    Time   DateTime
0  20041001  184531 2004-10-01
       Date    Time   DateTime  doye
0  20041001  184531 2004-10-01   275
```

### Method 2: use .dt (better :))

Ah, reading up on the `.dt` accessor [***here***](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0150-dt)... The `.dt` accessor for Pandas series treats every member of the series as a datetime so when you apply it to your series as a whole everything has to be a datetime. When you apply it to a column in your series the `apply()` function gets datetime objects, not series, so you have to use datetime methods.

So let's not use `apply()`. Selecting a column of datetime's will give you a series, which you then *can* use `.dt` on, so the example becomes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

data1 = [ {"Date" : "20041001", "Time" : 184531}]

frame1=pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Date','Time'])
frame1["DateTime"]= pd.to_datetime(frame1.Date, format="%Y%m%d", errors='raise')
print frame1
frame1["doye"] = frame1.DateTime.dt.dayofyear
print frame1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. The `%j` format code provides day-of-year.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['20041001', '20041002', '20041003'])
>>> df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
>>> df
           0
0 2004-10-01
1 2004-10-02
2 2004-10-03
>>> df['day_of_year'] = df[0].apply(lambda x: int(datetime.datetime.strftime(x,'%j')))
>>> df
           0  day_of_year
0 2004-10-01          275
1 2004-10-02          276
2 2004-10-03          277
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should do all the steps you are expecting:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
frame1 = pd.DataFrame({"Date" : [20041001, 20041001, 20041002, 20041002, 20041003],
                    "Time": [184531, 202316, 175015, 192822, 183314],
                    "VCD": [293.7, 305.4, 322.9, 316.6, 334.4]})

clw1 = frame1.drop_duplicates("Date")
clw1["Datetime"] = clw1["Date"].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(str(x), "%Y%m%d"))
clw1["doye"] = clw1["Datetime"].apply(lambda x: int(dt.datetime.strftime(x,'%j')))
```

Output for `clw1` is:

```
>>> clw1
       Date    Time    VCD             Datetime  doye
0  20041001  184531  293.7  2004-10-01 00:00:00   275
2  20041002  175015  322.9  2004-10-02 00:00:00   276
4  20041003  183314  334.4  2004-10-03 00:00:00   277
```

Comment: Thanks...... everyone. Finally I can understand apply, datetime, even dataframe.!!!!!